# Python .replace working in one place but not in the other

Tags: python, file, filesystems

I am currently writing a script for my own website that hosts games and a lot of them
So many games that I have to write a script to automatically create a file for each game
Now where I am stuck is that I am getting the name of the game from the name of the folder but replacing the start of the directory doesn't work talkin about C:\Users\user\Desktop\Newfolder\

Here is my code, it doesn't have the best formatting because I didn't think anyone else would need to see it

```
     for f,s in size_of_file: # file and size
             if round(s/(1*1),3) > 10000000:  # the hosting I'm using doesn't allow files above 10mb
                   print("Found Big File. Size: {} Path: {}".format(round(s/(1*1),3),os.path.join(path, f)))
                   gamename = path.replace(r'C:\Users\Logan\Desktop\Newfolder\'', r'') 
                   f = open("{}.html".format(gamename),"w",encoding="utf-8") # create html file for the game this for some reason DOES work and the game name is correct
                   f.write(bigfile.replace("PLEASEREPLACEMEWITHTHEGAMETHATYOUARETRYINGTOREPLACEMEWITHAWUFIAWUIFIGUWAFGIUAW",gamename)) #unique text so that I can replace it 
# for some reason here gamename is defined as C:\Users\Logan\Desktop\Newfolder\btd5 in comparison to where when I created the file it is only btd5
                   f.close()
             else:
                print("Found Small File. Size: {} Path: {}".format(round(s/(1*1),3),os.path.join(path, f)))
```

I tried to not use a variable and only use `path.replace(r'C:\Users\Logan\Desktop\Newfolder\'', r'')` 
but that did not work and I got the same results
Note: I'm not receiving any errors

Rest of the code here: https://pastebin.com/2fJarKwC
It was too big and I thought the formatting would be annoying

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get an error message? What was the result?

Comment: If you're trying to get the filename part of a pathname, use `os.path.basename()`.

Comment: Path is a variable, here's a pastebin with the rest of the code https://pastebin.com/2fJarKwC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is your friend, allowing you to avoid many gotchas from using `os.path`.

```py
from pathlib import Path


def do_stuff(directory: Path):
    files_list = [
        (fp, round(fp.stat().st_size, 3))
        for fp in directory.iterdir() 
        if fp.is_file()
    ]    
    for fp, s in files_list:
        if s > 10_000_000:
            print(f"Found Big File. Size: {s} Path: {fp}")
            gamename = fp.name
            html_content = bigfile.replace("PLEASEREPLACEMEWITHTHEGAMETHATYOUARETRYINGTOREPLACEMEWITHAWUFIAWUIFIGUWAFGIUAW", game_name)
            with fp.parent.joinpath(f"{gamename}.html").open("w") as html_file:
                html_file.write(html_content)
        else:
            print(f"Found Small File. Size: {s} Path: {fp}"


rootdir = Path(r'C:\Users\Logan\Desktop\Newfolder')
for item in rootdir.iterdir():
    if item.is_dir():
        do_stuff(item)
```

Comment: it is creating a file named after the file that is too big and not the folder name and in the  incorrect directory. It seems its naming gamename as the filename of the file thats too big and not the folder name

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the double quote mark after Newfolder in:

> path.replace(r'C:\Users\Logan\Desktop\Newfolder\'', r'')

should be:

> path.replace(r'C:\Users\Logan\Desktop\Newfolder' + '\\', r'')

I guess.
However you might want to consider using the pathlib which allows better handling and modifications of file system paths. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: the double quote is because a string cannot end in a backslash

Comment: True (I edited that in my answer), but you also cannot add an additional single quote. Replace won't find that quote in your string. You can work around that by adding another string that provides that ending backslash or move to pathlib. Your code would look nicer and also would be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to extract the game name from the directory path and use it for creating HTML files. The issue you're encountering might be related to how you're using the `path.replace()` function. You need to make sure that you're correctly extracting the game name from the directory path and cleaning it up.

```
import os

directory_path = r'C:\Users\Logan\Desktop\Newfolder'

for f, s in size_of_file:  # file and size
    if round(s / (1 * 1), 3) > 10000000:  # File size check
        print("Found Big File. Size: {} Path: {}".format(round(s / (1 * 1), 3), os.path.join(path, f)))
        
        # Extract game name from the directory path
        relative_path = os.path.relpath(path, directory_path)  # Get relative path
        game_name = os.path.basename(relative_path)  # Get the game name
        
        html_filename = "{}.html".format(game_name)
        html_content = bigfile.replace("PLEASEREPLACEMEWITHTHEGAMETHATYOUARETRYINGTOREPLACEMEWITHAWUFIAWUIFIGUWAFGIUAW", game_name)
        
        with open(html_filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write(html_content)
    else:
        print("Found Small File. Size: {} Path: {}".format(round(s / (1 * 1), 3), os.path.join(path, f)))
```

Comment: There is more code, But I didn't include it because I thought it wasn't necessary. path would be "C:\Users\Logan\Desktop\Newfolder\btd5" and if you would like to see the rest of the code here is a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/2fJarKwC